# Invalid use of '.' while trying to hide checkbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, powerapps-forms

I am trying to create simple formula like this `If([DateValueKey11].Selected.Value=false,true, false)`

But I am getting error in syntax that invalid use of '.'. Both fields are checkbox's that have to disappear if one of them is selected.

Using SP Cloud and PowerApps

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes and toggles do not have property "Selected" - in your example you are using DataCardValueKey - which might be just the "field title"

You should be able to simply use **DataCardValue11.Value** to control visibility of other element. No need to use "If"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As a supplement, here is an article about "Working With CheckBox Control In Microsoft PowerApps" for your reference:

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/working-with-checkbox-control-in-microsoft-powerapps/